# Sum between two numbers (including numbers between)

Tags: java, sum

I'm trying to get the sum of two numbers and all numbers between them. My trouble is ensuring that it doesn't matter if the first or second input is larger. This is what I've got so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BoundedSum
{

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int sum = 0;
    static int first;
    static int second;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("Input an integer (0,1,2,3...).");
        first = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Input a second integer. The sum of your inputs\nplus any numbers between them will be given.");
        second = input.nextInt();

        while(true)
        {

            if(first < second)
            {

                sum += first;
                first++;
            }

            if(second < first)
            {

                sum += second;
                second++;
            }

            if(first == second || second == first)
            {

                System.out.println("The sum = " + sum);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: look for a closed-form formula for this. Otherwise someone could give you two numbers very, very far apart and your code would be needlessly very slow.

Comment: 1) use a `for` loop, rather than a `while` as it's much cleaner and better to deal with. 2) `if(first == second || second == first)` can be simplified to `if(first == second)`

Comment: Please learn about `else` clauses.

Answer (score 3):

Use this formula for series sum:

```
n/2*{2*a+(n-1)*d}
```

where `n` = total terms/numbers
`a` = first term/number
`d` = difference  between two adjacent numbers

Answer (score 2):

You are effectively trying to calculate the [sum of an arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum). The only part "missing" in the formula is the number of elements, which can easily be deduced by subtracting the two bounds:

```
int sum = (Math.abs(first - second) + 1) * (first + second) / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop from the lower to the higher, I will do something like.

```
int low, high;
if(first<second){
    low = first;
    high = second;
} else{
    low = second;
    high = first;
}
```

Then do the loop:

```
for(int i = low; i<=second; i++){

}
```

Of course the equation is faster, but this seems to address your question.